# Как получить список видео на ютуб-канале

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Я хочу получить список всех видео на определённом канале youtube, как это можно сделать на c#?

Answer (score 3):

Гугл предоставляет [доступ к ютуб при помощи специального API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Нужно зарегистрироваться в [консоли разработчика](https://console.developers.google.com/) и получить API KEY - после чего можно делать запросы.

Гугл предоствляет для c# nuget-пакет Google.Apis.YouTube.V3 подключив который можно делать запросы.

Для поиска всех видео на канале, смотрим описание [метода Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). Есть и возможность поиграться с запросами прямо из браузера, посмотреть описание всех параметров и увидеть готовые фрагменты кода.

Например, ваш код может быть таким:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "apiKey",
        ApplicationName = "TestLinqpadScript",
    });

    var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
    searchListRequest.ChannelId = "UCMCgOm8GZkHp8zJ6l7_hIuA";
    searchListRequest.MaxResults = 10;
    searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Date;
    var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
    {
        switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
        {
            case "youtube#video":
                $"{Environment.NewLine}".Dump();
                searchResult.Id.VideoId.Dump();
                searchResult.Snippet.PublishedAt.Dump();
                searchResult.Snippet.Title.Dump();
                break;

            case "youtube#channel":
            case "youtube#playlist":
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Получаем примерно следующее в отладчике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что не рекомендуется использовать более 50ти результатов при поиске - следует читать параметр nextPageToken и подставлять его в pageToken следующего запроса.